# Question on custom adapter android

Tags: android, adapter, android-gallery

I am a little confused on custom adapters, especially for Gallery.  I have a list of objects, say Dogs. Here is the class for Dogs:

```
public static Dogs{
  public string name;
  public string breed;
  public string hometown;
}
```

What I want my gallery to print out is just the string name value for each element in my Dogs list.  How can I do that?  I am assuming I would have to do something in my getView method, but I am not sure what to do?? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hmm.. make one arraylist that contains object ref of Dogs. Now for each row for list that is  0..n your getview method would be called. you need pass this arraylist to the constructer of your custom adapter. in getsize method you need to pass the size of arraylist. Now when getView will be called automatically ... position of row ie row no is passed automatically. here you will use that postion as index for you arraylist and get the desired Dog object. And then there's a simple substitution of values. Cheers!

Comment: I know how to do it that way but I didn't want to resort to wasting more space by creating a new arraylist each time . Is there another way besides creating a new atraylist

Comment: What I mean is after I have an arraylist of dog objects how can I specify just to show the name variable??